# Polymer based disc brakes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, material-science

I know that you can have metallic and ceramic composite brakes.

My question is can you have disc brakes for a car that consists of polymetric materials or would this be impossible due to its low melt temperature ?

Comment: A thermoset rather than a thermoplastic might be an option, something like Bakelite, but burning may be a concern. It smelled nasty when highly heated. But scraping-off polymer molecules and dumping them in the environment, on mass scale, sounds dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but the disk in a disk brake system needs to absorb enourmous amounts of heat to dissipate the energy of motion. It then needs to transfer that heat to the air. Polymers generally are poor heat conductors and have relatively low heat capacity. Add to this lower strength and you have a poor choice for disk material. As Jim Clark mentions in his comment thermosetting polymers don't melt and can have higher degradation temperatures, but they will burn. All in all, it is hard to justify any polymer over something cheap and effective like cast iron.